# Sorting 9 numbers with 9 flips

Tags: combinatorics

You want to sort a sequence of numbers into ascending order. You can perform flips: take a sub-sequence of 4 numbers (a, b, c, d) and reverse their order to obtain (d, c, b, a). Can you sort the following sequence in 9 flips?

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a computer; if you consider that cheating pls ignore this answer:

> 12 solutions:

> [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [6 7 8 9 5 4 3 2 1] [6 5 9 8 7 4 3 2 1] [6 5 4 7 8 9 3 2 1] [6 5 4 7 8 1 2 3 9] [6 5 4 7 3 2 1 8 9] [6 5 4 1 2 3 7 8 9] [1 4 5 6 2 3 7 8 9] [1 2 6 5 4 3 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [6 7 8 9 5 4 3 2 1] [6 7 8 3 4 5 9 2 1] [6 7 8 3 2 9 5 4 1] [6 7 8 3 2 1 4 5 9] [6 7 1 2 3 8 4 5 9] [6 3 2 1 7 8 4 5 9] [1 2 3 6 7 8 4 5 9] [1 2 3 4 8 7 6 5 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 5 6 7 8 4 3 2 1] [9 5 4 8 7 6 3 2 1] [9 5 4 8 7 1 2 3 6] [9 5 4 8 3 2 1 7 6] [9 5 4 1 2 3 8 7 6] [1 4 5 9 2 3 8 7 6] [1 2 9 5 4 3 8 7 6] [1 2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 5 6 7 8 4 3 2 1] [7 6 5 9 8 4 3 2 1] [7 6 5 3 4 8 9 2 1] [7 6 5 3 2 9 8 4 1] [7 6 5 3 2 1 4 8 9] [7 6 1 2 3 5 4 8 9] [7 3 2 1 6 5 4 8 9] [1 2 3 7 6 5 4 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 4 5 6 7 3 2 1] [9 8 4 5 6 1 2 3 7] [9 8 4 5 3 2 1 6 7] [9 8 4 1 2 3 5 6 7] [1 4 8 9 2 3 5 6 7] [1 2 9 8 4 3 5 6 7] [1 2 3 4 8 9 5 6 7] [1 2 3 4 8 7 6 5 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 4 5 6 7 3 2 1] [9 6 5 4 8 7 3 2 1] [4 5 6 9 8 7 3 2 1] [4 5 6 3 7 8 9 2 1] [4 5 6 3 2 9 8 7 1] [4 5 6 3 2 1 7 8 9] [4 5 1 2 3 6 7 8 9] [4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 3 4 5 6 2 1] [9 8 7 3 2 6 5 4 1] [9 8 7 3 2 1 4 5 6] [9 8 1 2 3 7 4 5 6] [9 3 2 1 8 7 4 5 6] [1 2 3 9 8 7 4 5 6] [1 2 3 4 7 8 9 5 6] [1 2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 3 4 5 6 2 1] [3 7 8 9 4 5 6 2 1] [3 4 9 8 7 5 6 2 1] [3 4 5 7 8 9 6 2 1] [3 4 5 7 8 1 2 6 9] [3 4 5 7 6 2 1 8 9] [3 4 5 1 2 6 7 8 9] [1 5 4 3 2 6 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 6 2 3 4 5 1] [9 8 7 6 2 1 5 4 3] [9 8 1 2 6 7 5 4 3] [9 6 2 1 8 7 5 4 3] [1 2 6 9 8 7 5 4 3] [1 2 6 5 7 8 9 4 3] [1 2 6 5 4 9 8 7 3] [1 2 6 5 4 3 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 6 2 3 4 5 1] [9 8 7 4 3 2 6 5 1] [4 7 8 9 3 2 6 5 1] [4 3 9 8 7 2 6 5 1] [4 3 2 7 8 9 6 5 1] [4 3 2 7 8 1 5 6 9] [4 3 2 7 6 5 1 8 9] [4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 6 5 1 2 3 4] [9 8 1 5 6 7 2 3 4] [9 6 5 1 8 7 2 3 4] [1 5 6 9 8 7 2 3 4] [1 5 6 2 7 8 9 3 4] [1 5 6 2 3 9 8 7 4] [1 5 6 2 3 4 7 8 9] [1 5 4 3 2 6 7 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>  
>  [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1] [9 8 7 6 5 1 2 3 4] [9 8 7 6 3 2 1 5 4] [9 8 7 1 2 3 6 5 4] [1 7 8 9 2 3 6 5 4] [1 2 9 8 7 3 6 5 4] [1 2 3 7 8 9 6 5 4] [1 2 3 7 8 4 5 6 9] [1 2 3 7 6 5 4 8 9] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

With the benefit of hindsight we can construct a solution by hand:

> a trip are three flips in a row:
>  
>  an up trip: [1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 3 2 1 5 6] [4 5 1 2 3 6] [4 5 6 3 2 1] swaps two triplets and also reverses the one that moves up.
>  
>  a down trip: [1 2 3 4 5 6] [1 2 6 5 4 3] [1 4 5 6 2 3] [6 5 4 1 2 3] swaps two triplets and also reverses the one that moves down.
>  It is now easy to see that we can combine three trips for example the leftmost possible up trip before and after the rightmost possible down trip to form a solution.

Comment: Nice work! It is not cheating, but I was hoping that this puzzle is small enough to be solved by hand. Would you be able to format your answer so that there is a clear separation between different solutions. BTW are these all the possible solutions?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Done. Yes, these are all solutions with precisely 9 flips and without immediate cancellation (i.e. twice the same flip next to itself).

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I added a "by-hand" solution.

Comment: Very nice Paul!